# JavaFX stage opens behind other windows

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, stage

I am well aware with the setAlwaysOnTop javafx method which can bring the stage in front when clicked on the application. But the problem is that with setting `setAlwaysOnTop` to be true , the window appears always on top of other windows irrespective of whichever window we open . Even if I open chrome or firefox or any other window , my java fx application window would still lie on the top.
I want it to adjust the z value in order that it gets changed depending upon which window is currently being opened .
Instead of always setting the z value to be maximum , I want the `z order` to be adjustable .
Can anyone tell me how to do that.

Comment: I don't know if setting a window as n-th topmost window is even supported by operating systems... (And operating systems are responsible for determining the "z-order" in the end...)

Comment: So you mean to say that it is not possible to set the z value using javafx .It is in the control of operating systems ?

Comment: you want to control other opened applications ? naa, but idk what you want, but you can undo your static position with `primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);` then  `primaryStage.toBack();` and undo it back by setting it to true, don't know if that is what you want.